# How to reset or remove tag groups and tag lists in a DM script?

Tags: tags, dm-script

## How to reset or remove tag groups and tag lists in a DM script?

Some background:

I am preparing a script for analysing series of EELS spectra in GMS 2. I fit the background to a power-law modele and obtain the fitting parameters, both value and sigma, from the Tags in the background spectrum. However, if a try to analyse various edges in a single script I find that the sigma values of the fit parameters depends on the order of the calculation. To check this I show a script. If I only define the fitting region one time it works OK, but if I do that twice (only for testing, I know that is nonsense), the sigma values decreases. The result is the same if the fitting regions are different. I would like to reset or delete the TagGroup to check if then the problem is solved, but I am unable to do that.

```
TagGroup Tg
Number a0, sa0, a1, sa1
taggroup bandsTgs = NewTagList()
taggroup bandTg = NewTagGroup()

image spec := GetFrontImage()

// ...............First Time.....................................

bandTg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat( "start", 600 ) // calibrated value!
bandTg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat( "end", 800 )   // calibrated value!
bandsTgs.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup( Infinity(), bandTg )

image bkg1 := EELSFitPowerLawBackground( spec, bandsTgs )
bkg1.ShowImage()

tg = bkg1.ImageGetTagGroup() // Fit parameters(in eV) from the BKG spectrum Tags

tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a0:value", a0 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a0:sigma", sa0 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a1:value", a1 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a1:sigma", sa1 )

Result("\n Fitting BKG parameters. First time ") 
Result("\n    a0 : " + a0)
Result("\n   sa0 : " + sa0)
Result("\n    a1 : " + a1)
Result("\n   sa1 : " + sa1)

// Second Time........I get a differetn result if a repeat the fit-region definition

bandTg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat( "start", 600 ) // calibrated value! 
bandTg.TagGroupSetTagAsFloat( "end", 800 )   // calibrated value!
bandsTgs.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup( Infinity(), bandTg )

image bkg2 := EELSFitPowerLawBackground( spec, bandsTgs )
bkg2.ShowImage()

tg = bkg2.ImageGetTagGroup() // Fit parameters(in eV) from the BKG spectrum Tags

tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a0:value", a0 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a0:sigma", sa0 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a1:value", a1 )
tg.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Processing:[0]:Parameters:Fit Parameters:a1:sigma", sa1 )

Result("\n")
Result("\n Fitting BKG parameters. Second time ")
Result("\n    a0 : " + a0)
Result("\n   sa0 : " + sa0)
Result("\n    a1 : " + a1)
Result("\n   sa1 : " + sa1)

bandsTgs.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "BandTags", 0 ) // To show the Tag structure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is an a bit more comprehensive description of **tags** in DigitalMicrograph:

---

Be aware that

> There exist *simplified* wrapper commands for *simple* scripts

such as

```
image img := RealImage( "", 4, 10 )
SetNumberNote( img, "TagPath:With:SubTag:TagName", 12.2 )
DeleteNote( img, "TagPath:With:SubTag:TagName")
```

However, the underlaying object is the `TagGroup` object with a lot of specific commands. You can always also achieve the *simple* things with the *complete* object, of course.

---

Next, it is important to know that

> There is a difference between `TagGroup` and `TagList`.

Both are `TagGroup` objects on the surface, but some commands will only work on either of them. *TagLists* have indexed entries and *TagGroups* have labelled entries.

[image: TagGroup vs TagList]

The difference of the two becomes important when you start to insert into the group / list or want to remove from them, and it also becomes important when you traverse the structure.

Also note that `TagGroup` entries are alphanumerically sorted while `TagList` entries are sorted by the index.

Some examples:

- commands of form `TagGroupInsertTagAs...` `TagGroupGetIndexedTagAs...` work only on `TagLists`
- commads of form `TagGroupSetTagAs...` `TagGroupGetTagAs...`  work only on `TagGroups`
- To delete a tag from a `TagList` you need to use `TagGroupDeleteTagWithIndex`
- To delete a tag from a `TagGroup` you need to use `TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel`

Sometimes you can work around this issue by using the *index* in a `TagList` as a *label* by putting it in between `[` and `]` as a tag-path. But there are also some circumstances when you need the difference of 'TagGroup' and 'TagList'

---

> There are different options to delete tags

- `TagGroupDeleteAllTags()` deletes 'all' sub-tags of a *TagGroup* or *TagList* - but not the group/list entry itself.
- `TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel()` deletes a specif tag within a *TagGroup* specified by the label.
- `TagGroupDeleteTagWithIndex()` deletes a specif tag within a *TagList* specified by the index. Note, that this changes the indices of the other entries!

---

### Example

The code below creates the tagGroup from the image above:

```
tagGroup rootTg = NewTagGroup()
tagGroup tg = NewTagGroup()
tagGroup tl = NewTagList()

tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "value", "I am a string tag")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "2", "My tag at #2")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Name", "Hello")
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "1", "My tag at #1")

tl.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( 0, "String tag #1" )
tl.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( 1, "String tag #2" )
tl.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( 2, "String tag #3" )
tl.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( 1, "String tag #4" )

rootTg.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "TagGroup", tg )
rootTg.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "TagList", tl )

rootTg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "TagGroup example", 0 )
```

To delete the "Name: Hello" tag (which is the 3rd tag in the sorted group), we would use either of the three:

```
rootTg.TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel( "TagGroup:Name" )
tg.TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel( "Name" )
tg.TagGroupDeleteTagWithIndex( 2 )
```

To delete the 3rd entry in the TagList, we would use either of the three:

```
rootTg.TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel( "TagList:[2]" )
tl.TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel( "[2]" )
tl.TagGroupDeleteTagWithIndex( 2 )
```

To delete the whole TagList, we would use

```
rootTg.TagGroupDeleteTagWithLabel( "TagList" )
```